# Sending const char to a function and getting out of range

Tags: c, sockets, memory

I am trying to send my port number to a function as const char *. The memory address on receiving is out of range. Can someone tel me what is the correct way of doing this ?

This is my code

Inside main()

```
     socket_open("host", 12345); // host and port number
```

On function side

```
     socket_open(char * host,int port) {
     int error;
     struct addrinfo hints;
     struct addrinfo *res;
     ...
     error = getaddrinfo(host,(char *)port,&hints,&res);
```

I get a segmentation on getaddrinfo. 12345 is too big for char* it seems. How should i fix this ??

Comment: 1. Doesn't look like any problem in the code. I recommend including more of your code.

2. When you type cast from int to char*, there would be no loss of precision or data as both of them have same size (due to both of them being int internally). So the 'out of range' int may not be the problem.

Comment: You can't cast an `int` to `char*` and pass it to a function expecting a terminated string. And adding insult to injury, your "hints" being passed are entirely indeterminate (i.e. you've never filled them out and they're filled with junk). [The documentation of `getaddrinfo()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) is probably worth a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getaddrinfo` is expecting a string you must convert `port` (an `int`) to one first.  Here is one way:

```
char portStr[MAX_PORT_STR_LEN];
snprintf(portStr, MAX_PORT_STR_LEN, "%d", port);
```

Now you can send it to `getaddrinfo`:

```
error = getaddrinfo(host, portStr, &hints, &res);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe port should really be a character representation of the port based on what the documentation says here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getaddrinfo.html

```
char szPort[20];
sprintf(szPort, "%d", port);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an int in parameter port. Then you pass it to a function that interprets it as a character pointer, and starts reading characters from the address in the int until a zero is found. But the address points out of your readable memory segment. Or if no zero is found, it keeps reading until you get a segmentation fault.

Convert your number properly into a string.

See @Raz Wilson's answer.